# Building emulator for AOSP 4.2.2 with make -j4

Tags: build, android-emulator, android-source

I am trying to build emulator for Android open source project (AOSP) 4.2.2 and when I compile `make -j4`, I get the following error.

```
ost C: acp <= build/tools/acp/acp.c
host C: libhost <= build/libs/host/CopyFile.c
host C++: libandroidfw <= frameworks/base/libs/androidfw/AssetDir.cpp
host C++: libandroidfw <= frameworks/base/libs/androidfw/AssetManager.cpp
/var/folders/1v/7qwg76xn3fs34bpkbj7sw0k00000gq/T//ccmomvtt.s:1854:FATAL:Symbol _isSourceNewer.eh already defined.
/var/folders/1v/7qwg76xn3fs34bpkbj7sw0k00000gq/T//ccGfRe2w.s:829:FATAL:Symbol _process.eh already defined.
make: *** [out/host/darwin-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libhost_intermediates/CopyFile.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [out/host/darwin-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/acp_intermediates/acp.o] Error 1
```

What is going wrong? I followed source website to build this. My system configuration: Mac OS 10.7.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the what the problem is. I did couple of things to make this work.

1. Remove any previous version of Xcode on your machine running on
   OS x 10.7.
2. Look for Developer/ folder in the home directory. Move that to trash (It belongs to Xcode)
3. Reinstall Xcode 4.2 (which I used and it worked)
4. Follow the AOSP documentation to update the rest using macports.